# Find and count specific value from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have pass trough array to get all ROLE field results from db.

Not I need to search them to find just ROLE_ADMIN roles and count them.

```
"users": [
    [
        "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
    ],
    [
        "ROLE_STRATEGIST",
        "ROLE_ADMIN"
    ],
    [
        "ROLE_EDITOR"
    ],
    [
        "ROLE_STRATEGIST",
        "ROLE_ADMIN"
    ],
]
```

And this is my code:

```
$users = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();

    $countUsers = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $countUsers[] = $user->getRoles();
    }

    return $countUsers;
```

Is there a way to go trough array and count all ROLE_ADMIN results?

Comment: Something like `$role_admin_counter += in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $user->getRoles()) ? 1 : 0;` …?

Comment: Yap! This was great, thanks! @04FS

Answer (score 1):

If the input is available as an array as shown, it can also be implemented with the [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-reduce.php) function.

```
$users = [
    ["ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"],
    ["ROLE_STRATEGIST","ROLE_ADMIN"],
    ["ROLE_EDITOR"],
    ["ROLE_STRATEGIST","ROLE_ADMIN"],
];

$role = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
$count = array_reduce(
  $users,
  function($carry,$item) use($role){return $carry + (int)in_array($role,$item);},
  0
);

var_dump($count); //int(2)
```